# rqt_gui shows no menu bar on Mac OSX

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, rqt, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

I'm expecting `file`, `plugin` and other menus like this:
[image description http://ros.org/wiki/rqt?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ros_gui.png](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ros_gui.png)

I followed [Homebrew source](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source?highlight=%28%28groovy%7CInstallation%7COSX%7CHomebrew%7CSource%29%29) installation. Versions are:

```
rosuser-mac1:src nrosuser$ cat .rosinstall|grep rqt_gui
- tar: {local-name: rqt_gui, uri: 'https://github.com/ros-gbp/rqt-release/archive/release/rqt_gui/0.2.8.tar.gz', version: rqt-release-release-rqt_gui-0.2.8}
rosuser-mac1:src nrosuser$ cat .rosinstall|grep qt_gui_core
- tar: {local-name: qt_gui_core, uri: 'https://github.com/ros-gbp/qt_gui_core-release/archive/release/qt_gui_core/0.2.12.tar.gz', version: qt_gui_core-release-release-qt_gui_core-0.2.12}
```

(I'm still figuring out what's the best way to get the version in use on `OSX`.)

OSX 10.8.2, ROS Groovy

Any idea? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59480/rqt_gui-shows-no-menu-bar-on-mac-osx/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a bug. I fixed it two months ago, but qt_gui_core has not been released since then:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/commit/9cba48199c039cdca013a7ee12a06ef3070f829d

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1